# Exclude branches from build (Azure Pipelines)

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to exclude branches from build by Azure Pipelines.
I do not want to specify this within the configuration on the web platform of Azure.
Instead I want to specify this inside the `azure-pipeline.yml`.
So what I did is this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - artifacts

strategy:
  matrix:
    ubuntu_16_04_gcc_8:
      imageName: 'ubuntu-16.04'
      CC: gcc-8
      CXX: g++-8
      the_name: 'Azure Pipelines'

    windows_2019:
      imageName: 'windows-2019'
      the_name: 'Azure Pipelines'

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)
  name: $(the_name)


steps:
 - script: git submodule update --init --recursive
   displayName: "Init Git Submodules"
   condition: succeeded()
 - script: cmake -S . -B ./build/
   displayName: "CMake: Create Project"
   condition: succeeded()
# and some more steps here
```

The expected behavior is that no builds are started for branch `artifacts`.
But actually builds are still triggered.
How do I need to change the `yml` to achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The expected behavior is that no builds are started for branch artifacts. But actually builds are still triggered. How do I need to change the yml to achieve the expected behavior?

I test your YAML file, but did not reproduce your problem.

To resolve this issue, please check following suggestion:

- Check the YAML file under the `artifacts` branch. If I set trigger in the `artifacts` like this:

  ```
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - '*'
  ```

  The pipeline will always be triggered, no matter how you set the trigger in `azure-pipeline.yml`.
- Check the Triggers setting on the trigger tab, to check if you check the checkbox `Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here`:

  [image]

Comment: Right now I see that I did not see the forest for the trees. The error seems to be that in my whole setup the yml changed have not yet been merged to the artifacts branch.